# Finding the Equation of a Tangent Line to a Parabola Using Vector Approach and Parametric Equations

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

A line $t$ passes through the point $A(-3, 0)$ and is tangent to the parabola with equation $\lambda: x=3y^2$ at point $P$. What is the equation of line $t$?

Well, I could try using the equation for a line $t:y=mx+n$, and substitute its equation into the parabola equation, calculating the determinant and finding the slope. However, I would like to solve this problem using the vector approach of Analytic Geometry, that is, if $t \cap \lambda = P(a, b)$, then the parametric equation of the line will be given by
$$t: \begin{cases} x= -3 + (a+3)t \\ y=0+bt\end{cases}$$

Comment: There are two ways this can be solved. The calculus way is to differentiate the parabola: $\frac{dx}{dy} = 6y$, to get the slope of the tangent to $x$ as a function of $y$. So at $(a,b)$, the tangent line has equation $(x - a) = 6b(y-b)$, while the line through $(-3,0)$ and $(a,b)$ has equation $(x-a) = \frac{a+3}{b-0}(y-b)$, meaning that you need $a,b$ to satisfy $\frac{a+3}b = 6b$, while also $a = 3b^2$.

Comment: The second way, which does not involve calculus, is to assume the tangent will only intersect the parabola in a single point (true for this curve, but not in general). Therefore you take the equation of a line through $(-3.0)$, say $x+3 = m(y-0)$, so $x = my - 3$, and intersect that with $x =3y^2$, which means supposing that a certain $(x,y)$ satisfies both equations that the same time. This allows you to substitute one expression for $x$ with the other to get $3y^2 = my - 3$, or $3y^2 -my +3 = 0$. Thus $y = (m \pm\sqrt{m^2 - 36})/6$, This gives two points of intersection unless $m \pm 6$.

Comment: I *think* the second way is the first method you mention, but your discription misuses the language, so I cannot be sure. This method *intersects* the two equations (i.e., finds a common solution). It does not "substitute" one equation into the other. And $\sqrt{m^2 - 36}$ is the "discriminate", not the "determinant", which is something matrices have, nor quadratics. But in any case, you have to somehow interpret what it means for a line to be tangent to the curve, and that means either involving calculus, or examinging intersections.